# When you fly for free using miles, do you earn miles?

Tags: loyalty-programs, oneworld, american-airlines

Two questions:

- If I "buy" a flight using miles, will I earn miles on that flight? In my case, I'd be using American Airlines miles to buy an American Airlines flight.
- What about if I use American Airlines miles to "buy" a flight on some other [oneworld](http://www.oneworld.com/) carrier, like Japan Air Lines? Will I earn JAL miles or AA miles?

Comment: I wonder if there is any program that gives mileage on award ticket... Anyone knows about it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No, you don't**!

From the [terms and conditions](http://www.americanairlines.co.uk/i18n/AAdvantage/programInformation/termsConditions.jsp) of American Airlines AAdvantage program:

> You may accrue mileage only for purchased, eligible, published-fare
>   tickets on qualifying routes used in accordance with all applicable
>   conditions of carriage, tariffs, rules and terms of ticketing and
>   travel. AAdvantage mileage accrual eligibility on airline participant
>   routes is subject to change without notice.

and even more clear:

> Certain airline tickets are **not eligible** for earning mileage credit.
>   These include, without limitation, the following: **all tickets issued
>   as AAdvantage awards** or other free ticket promotions including free or
>   reduced rate tickets;...

As you don't get new mileage on AA, you most certainly also don't get any on any other airline.

Comment: What about for Chase reward points?  If you book a flight using chase reward points (ultimate rewards as part of the Chase Sapphire Credit Card) I asked a customer service representative and they said you can indeed earn and accrue miles on a flight even if you used your credit card reward points to purchase that flight