# Spend miles from one loyalty scheme, earn on another (within Skyteam)

Tags: airlines, loyalty-programs, korean-air, skyteam, flying-blue

Due to poor miles management, I end up owning ~4,000 miles on Flying Blue (Air France) and ~8,000 miles with SKYPASS (Korean Air), both of which belong to SkyTeam. I'd rather own Flying Blue miles as I actually travel from and to France more often but do not really wish losing the earned Korean miles either.

My question is: **can I spend SKYPASS miles to book a discounted** (or free) **flight while earning miles** (for this newly booked flight) **on Flying Blue?**

I know that I can't transfer miles from one airline to the other so I'm looking at the best strategy to make the most of my remaining SKYPASS miles while earning Flying Blue miles for all future journeys.

Many thanks,

Comment: As a rule of thumb you can not earn miles for flights booked (only) with miles.

Comment: A small exception is part-pay with miles (avios) which is offered by BA, which does allow you to earn miles on the underlying fare. I haven't heard of anything similar for skyteam though.

Comment: That's good to know, I might as well spend the maximum amount of SKYPASS miles on a free flight, then I'll earn everything else on Flying Blue (and forget about SKYPASS) :)

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Can I switch airline loyalty schemes and retain my benefits?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60864)*. As noted, the answer to *[When you fly for free using miles, do you earn miles?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4703)* is generally *no*.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

Any flight you book with miles does not give you miles, they are always excluded.